# count the number of a specific tag in the text

Tags: javascript, regex

is available var text is  a type:

```
<p>wtjeopitjeltgjelktg <h2> erigjeogjl <h3> <p> etc
```

I need count the number of tags `<p>`

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you already tried, not just drop off your requirements. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: This is even not a valid html

Comment: so match the tag..... using reg exp to match html is a bad idea.

Comment: i know, its example. I have random text in var text with tags, and I need count the number of tags <p>

Comment: yeah all text in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple count

using this

```
var temp = "<p>wtjeopitjeltgjelktg <h2> erigjeogjl <h3> <p> etc ";
var count = (temp.match(/<p>/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: hopefully the tags are not `<p class="">`

Comment: I think answer is correct as per requirement.

Comment: yeah, this is it!!! tnx

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and select the paragraphs using [document.querySelectorAll('p')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) :

```js
var text = `<p>wtjeopitjeltgjelktg <h2> erigjeogjl <h3> <p> etc `;

var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

const paragraphs = parsed.querySelectorAll('p');

console.log(paragraphs.length);
```

Comment: Proper approach to solve such problems +1

Answer (score 1):

Using a regualr expression can produce the wrong number of elements. Best way would be to convert it to HTML and use DOM.

```js
var str = '<p>hello</p><p class="foo">world</p><p style="color: red">apple</p>'

var div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = str;
var count = div.getElementsByTagName("p").length
console.log(count)
```

[A regular expression is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/), but a basic one would be

```js
var str = '<p>hello</p><p class="foo">world</p><p style="color: red">apple</p><param>aaaa</param>'
var matches = str.match(/<p(\s[^>]*)?>/g)
var count = matches ? matches.length : 0
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score -2):

If in frontend You can achieve with Jquery `$('p').length`.

If you are looking for a backend function you can use `Cheerio`